# How to create a id(autoincremented) in Mysql with a string concatenate with it? using php only

Tags: php, mysql

need to create a id having primary key with auto incrementation + a string has to be stored with that id using php like:
my sql has to show-

1. ID
2. WFS001
3. WFS002
4. WFS003
5. WFS005
6. .
7. .
8. .
9. .

Comment: For doing that i suggest you to have another table into which you store the "actual" value, like 001 or 005

Comment: Why don't you just have ordinary integer auto incrementation field, to who you just prepend your text `WFS`, like `sprintf('WFS%03d', $row['id'])`...

Comment: @Glavić u gave me solution thank u man..!! post as answer.

Comment: PLease include some code what you have tries so far...

Comment: actually i'm trying to implementing the code using answers of u people.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to have an auto increment column, do the insert, get the last id with [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) and make an update using another column and the last insert id + string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `CONCAT`, `LAST_INSERT_ID` and `LPAD` functions.

***Example with SELECT***:

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'WFS', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 2, '0'));
```

***Samples***:

```
mysql>     SELECT CONCAT( 'WFS', LPAD( 6, 3, '0'));
+----------------------------------+
| CONCAT( 'WFS', LPAD( 6, 3, '0')) |
+----------------------------------+
| WFS006                           |
+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: As good as the answer is, this isn't really scalable. You might want to consider fixing your data structure instead.